# How to set root directory in php

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I am developing a website based on MVC Design Pattern.

I need to access to another folder from `public` folder but the problem is it recognizes public folder as root directory. I checked path using `window.location.pathname` in javascript and it returns `/` so it's literally impossible to access to out of root directory.

I guess `.htaccess` file redirects the path. can anyone let me know how to set `Web` folder as root directory ?

[image: path]

.htaccess in Web

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't access your server's file system with Javascript!

Comment: please check .conf files of apache i.e. configirution file

Comment: With those `.htaccess` rules your serwer document root is public and everything outside is not accessible, if you want to access it maybe you should place it in you public directory?

Comment: @brzuchal can I modify .htaccess to set Web directory as root directory ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is a reason why all the public stuff are in `public` directory. It protects your application from unauthorised access to codes, configs etc.

Comment: @brzuchal thanks for answering. however, I am using ajax in public folder and my php file is in application dir.

Comment: @Daniel you've got `index.php` in public and you should be able to call that throu your application frontcontroller your application commands and queries thats what it is for in MVC, breaking those rules is making your application unsecure and unpredictable, your frontcontroller is your main guard here

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to access files outside of your webroot with JS. However, you could create a Symlink in your public folder.

```
ln -s web/your/file web/public/symlink
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this code to set root dir. in your index file. It may help you to web as root.

```
    if(!defined('ROOT_PATH')) define('ROOT_PATH','./'); //root path. Damn directories
    define('ROOT_DIR',str_replace('\\\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))).'/'); #Get real path for root dir ---linux and windows

print_r(ROOT_DIR);
```

Answer (score 0):

set this path to your index file.

$path = "http://www.yourdomain.com/";

define ( 'PATH', $path );

and every where you can call "PATH" variable in php you can do vardump(PATH);

i hope this is helpfull.. for u